# TextView should be displayed with ... character at the end

Tags: android, textview

i have created a textview with the below code:

```
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/txtDescription" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:maxLines="5">
```

As above, i have set the 5 Lines as maximum for the textview.

But my doubt is: if the string which i am going to display in Textview if it exceeds 5 lines, then it will be fitted upto 5 lines ending with "..." characters.

e.g.

```
Hello this is the demo of 
string which i have 
created especially for
the demo of textview
and setting maximum...
```

As same as above, i want to display in TextView output.

Pls give me suggestion, code or any link.

Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [`android:ellipsize`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aellipsize).

Comment: @Kcoppock exact solution that i wants, but let me know, when i use android:ellipsize attribute, at that time should i remove or keep the attribute android:maxLines="5" as same ?

Comment: @kcoppock see what happens now when i use android:ellipsize, if i am having string in 2 paragraph, then each paragraphs first 2 lines are displayed and then ellipsized at end.

Comment: Hmm, playing around with it now, even with maxLines on, it still ellipses it at 2 lines. I'm not sure why that is.

Comment: @kcoppock ya exactly ellipses it at 2 lines even with maxLines on

Comment: Does the same even with android:lines or android:minLines as well. Strange. :( I'm not really sure why that is; the only time I've ever used it was for a single line.

Comment: So I wonder, would it be possible to extend TextView and just override the setEllipsize() function and fix the issue manually?